# Find record closest to a given date for each group - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am new to sql.  Suppose we have a table like this:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+
|userid | statusid |   date    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| 1     |  1       | 2018-10-10| 
| 1     |  2       | 2018-10-12|
| 2     |  1       | 2018-09-25|
| 2     |  1       | 2018-10-01|
+-------+----------+-----------+
```

I need to get the stateid of each userid for a date as close to a given one as possible.  Say my given date is 2018-10-01.  How would I do that?  I tried various groupby's and partition by, but nothing works.  Could someone please help?

EDIT: my db is amazon redshift

Comment: Would the `date` always be greater than or equal to the `given date`?

Comment: If the given date were 2018-10-11, would you want to show statusid 1 or 2 or both for userid 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` window analytic function with ordered by absolute value of date difference.

*( Note that `row_number()` doesn't work for `MySQL 8-`, so that function is not used but `abs()` function is. )*

I don't know your `DBMS`

This solution is for `Oracle` :

```
with tab(userid, statusid, "date") as
(
 select 1,1,date'2018-10-10' from dual union all
 select 1,2,date'2018-10-12' from dual union all
 select 2,1,date'2018-09-25' from dual union all
 select 2,1,date'2018-10-02' from dual
)
select tt.userid, tt.statusid, tt."date"
  from
(
select t.userid, t.statusid , t."date",
       row_number() over (partition by t.userid 
                          order by abs("date" - date'2018-10-01')) as rn
  from tab t
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo for Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3838537d4f596ca837ae6c40efebe8ba)</kbd>

This solution is for `SQL Server` :

```
with tab([userid], [statusid], [date]) as
(
 select 1,1,'2018-10-10' union all
 select 1,2,'2018-10-12' union all
 select 2,1,'2018-09-25' union all
 select 2,1,'2018-10-02' 
)
select tt.[userid], tt.[statusid], tt.[date]
  from
(
select t.[userid], t.[statusid] , t.[date], 
       row_number() over (partition by t.[userid] 
                          order by abs(datediff(day,[date],'2018-10-01'))) as rn
  from tab t
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62e65a5798563a6660728fb5f7fe1e1f)</kbd>

The solution is for `My SQL`:

```
select tt.userid, tt.statusid, tt.date
  from
  (
   select t.userid, t.statusid , t.date,
          @rn := if(@iter = t.userid, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
          @iter := t.userid, 
          abs(date - date'2018-10-01') as df
     from tab t
     join (select @iter := 0, @rn := 0) as q_iter
    order by t.userid, abs(date - date'2018-10-01') 
  ) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo for My SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ca653a8ab5bdaeec748aaae518891d1f)</kbd>

This solution is for `PostGRES` :

```
with tab(userid, statusid, date) as
(
 select 1,1,'2018-10-10' union all
 select 1,2,'2018-10-12' union all
 select 2,1,'2018-09-25' union all
 select 2,1,'2018-10-02' 
)
select tt.userid, tt.statusid, tt.date
  from
(
select t.userid, t.statusid , t.date, 
       row_number() over (partition by t.userid
                          order by abs(date::date-'2018-10-01'::date)) as rn
  from tab t
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo for PostGRESql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b9802e053fce40b6b4548dafb0ed36eb)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this type of problem, you want the date on or before the given date.

If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.date <= '2018-10-01'
               );
```